# Exercise 6, Section 3.5 of Hoffman’s Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, proof-writing, linear-transformations

> Let $m$ and $n$ be positive integers and $F$ a field. Let $f_1,…,f_n$ be linear functionals on $F^n$. For $\alpha$ in $F^n$ define
> $T(\alpha) = (f_1(\alpha),…,f_m(\alpha))$.
> Show that $T$ is a linear transformation from $F^n$ into $F^m$. Then show that every linear transformation from $F^n$ into $F^m$ is of the above form, for some $f_1,…,f_n$.

**My attempt:** let $\alpha, \beta\in F^n$ and $c\in F$. Then $T(c\cdot \alpha+\beta)$ $=(f_1(c\cdot \alpha+\beta),…,f_m(c\cdot \alpha+\beta))$. Since $f_1,…,f_n$ are linear map, we have $(f_1(c\cdot \alpha+\beta),…,f_m(c\cdot \alpha+\beta))$ $= (c\cdot f_1( \alpha) +f_1(\beta),…,c\cdot f_m( \alpha)+f_m(\beta))$ $=c\cdot (f_1(\alpha),…,f_m(\alpha))$ $+$ $(f_1(\beta),…,f_m(\beta))$ $=c\cdot T(\alpha)+T(\beta)$. Thus $T(c\cdot \alpha +\beta)$ $=c\cdot T(\alpha)+T(\beta)$. Hence $T$ is linear map.

Let $T:F^n\to F^m$ be a linear map. We need to show $T$ is of $T(\alpha)=(f_1(\alpha),…,f_m(\alpha))$ form, for some $f_1,…,f_m$ linear functional on $F^n$. Let $\alpha \in F^n$. Then $\alpha=x_1\cdot e_1+…+x_n\cdot e_n$. Since $T$ is linear map, we have $T(\alpha)$ $=T(x_1\cdot e_1+…+x_n\cdot e_n)$ $=x_1\cdot T(e_1)+…+x_n\cdot T(e_n)$. Let $T(e_k)=(\alpha_{1k},…,\alpha_{mk})$, $\forall k\in J_n$. So $T(\alpha)$ $= x_1\cdot T(e_1)+…+x_n\cdot T(e_n)$ $=(\sum_{i\in J_n}x_i\cdot \alpha_{1i},…,\sum_{i\in J_n}x_i\cdot \alpha_{mi})$. Define $\forall j\in J_m$, $f_j:F^n\to F$ such that $f_j(\alpha)$ $=f_j((x_1,…,x_n))$ $=\sum_{i\in J_n}x_i\cdot \alpha_{ji}$. Hence $T(\alpha)$ $= (\sum_{i\in J_n}x_i\cdot \alpha_{1i},…,\sum_{i\in J_n}x_i\cdot \alpha_{mi})$ $=(f_1(\alpha),…,f_m(\alpha))$. **Is my proof correct?**

Comment: What is $J_n$? The proof is the same as you'd do in $\mathbf{R}^d,$ which is to expand on the canonical bases (which is what you do). So you are correct or on the right tracks.

Comment: @WilliamM. $J_n=\{1,…,n\}$

Comment: Next time try adding relevant notation to the post. Recall that Hoffmann and Kunze is an archaic book that is rarely used nowadays (only old mathematicians would suggest reading it considering there is a bazillion better references now).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your proof looks correct. There's actually a slightly
simpler way to do this. Let $n,m \in \mathbb{N}$ be given. Define the $j$-th projection map, with $j \in J_m$, as follows:
$$\pi_j: F^m \to F \ , \ (x_1,\ldots,x_m) \mapsto x_j$$
You can easily show that this is a linear map. Now, define:
$$f_j := \pi_j \circ T$$
This is certainly a linear map because it's a composition of two linear maps. Now, let $i \in J_m$. Then:
$$T_i(\alpha) = (\pi_i \circ T)(\alpha) = f_i(\alpha)$$
where $T_i(\alpha)$ denotes the $i$-th component of $T(\alpha)$. So, that completes the argument. This is actually not so different from what you did but it's conceptually better on the whole.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Why I didn’t think of this solution? Minor typo $i\in J_m$ instead of $i\in J_n$ and $\pi_j:F^m\to F$.

Comment: I've corrected the typos! So, at this point, my advice would be to try and delve into other books to see how other authors are thinking about the same material. You're at the stage now where you seem to have some mastery over writing out formal arguments. You should start trying to get a big picture perspective so that all of these arguments seem more natural to you.

Comment: I’m sorry for late reply. I just cross 2k rep. It unlock some privileges, I was exploring that. Thank you so much for your  encouraging words. In your opinion, which book I should study. Because there are lots of books in linear algebra. I sometimes read/skim linear algebra done right by Axler, Advance linear algebra by Steven Roman, Paul Halmos, etc.

Comment: Sterling Berberian's book is the best introductory treatment of linear algebra that I know, it's quite abstract and probably the best thing for a budding algebraist to read. Janich was the first linear algebra book that I ever read and I absolutely adore it, even though it's not really meant for people who would want to delve deep into Algebra. Linear Algebra by Kostrikin is fantastic and it's more geared towards geometry, while Linear Algebra by Werner Greub is geared towards algebraists but is not really meant to be a first treatment.

Comment: Whenever possible, you should try to, at the very least, skim through much more advanced books on any topic that you're learning. The thing about advanced books is that authors who are writing assume that the reader has seen quite a bit of math so they tend to give a big picture perspective on the material. It's not something you always need to internalize BUT it makes sure that you stay interested in the material and it familiarizes you with other arguments that people tend to use when proving these results.

Comment: I would like to say more about this but it's probably best if I do it in the context of an actual question. If you do ask a question about this over here, then send a comment in this post and I'll answer that question with more recommendations & more stuff to say about all of this.

Comment: Damm… you suggested some great linear algebra book. First book is really really good. I skim through chapter 1 & 2 and read some section on matrix. That book is complete, concise and have nice exercise problems. Third and fourth book are quite advance, especially after 2-3 chapter. Your second last comment is so true. When I was studying topology from Munkres, I used to also read/skim from Dugundji and Engelking topology book.

Comment: Yep. Berberian is the best that I have ever seen for an introductory treatment. There's one by Friedberg, Insel and Spence which is similar but I don't really like its style. The thing about Berberian that makes it lovely is the fact that it doesn't focus on working with bases and so on super early.  So, the proofs you're getting are actually quite a bit general. It's good that you had that habit with topology, especially because Munkres (as a topology book, in my honest opinion, is bad) so you definitely would need an extra source.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138271/discussion-between-user264745-and-mordeus-morgenstern).